# Calculate volume of a wedge of a sphere

Tags: calculus

The problem asks to find the volume of the smaller wedge cut from a sphere of radius a by two planes that intersect along a diameter at an angle of π/6.

I understand why $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}} \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{a} p^2 $sin$\phi$   $dp d\phi d\theta $ gives me the integral as in the answer here:
http://www.math.umn.edu/~rogness/umtymp/sec12.7num35.pdf

What I don't understand is why the integral

$ \int_{0}^{\pi}  \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}} \int_{0}^{a} p^2 $sin$\phi$   $dp d\phi d\theta $

does not give the correct answer. It integrates over the same wedge, it just positions the wedge opening from the top rather than the side.

Comment: FYI, that symbol $\rho$ on the linked page is not the letter $p$; it's the Greek letter called "rho". Using MathJax, `$\rho$` is shown as $\rho$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite the same wedge. Remember that $\phi$ is your variable that goes 
"up and down" from the poles, perpendicular to the equator. So this would give you a section of the the sphere that looks a bit like an ice cream cone that has been cut in half.

Why? You're going from the "north pole" to $\frac{\pi}{6}$, and then rotating that arc half way around (since $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\pi$).

Comment: I'm not sure I see how it looks like a cone cut in half

Comment: Hm. Some books use different definitions of the $\phi$ variable. My definition is that $\phi = 0$ starts at the north pole, and extends all the way down the the south pole at $\phi = \pi$. Is this true for you too?

Comment: yes, same for me.

Comment: The thing to remember is, $\phi$ and $\theta$ are not interchangeable. Not at all. For example, if you set $\phi = 0$, you get the same point no matter how you set $\theta$. If you set $\theta = 0$ you can get many different points depending on how you set $\phi$. The equation $\theta = k$ (constant $k$) is the equation of a plane, but $\phi = k$ is the equation of a cone.

Comment: The book solution given is a little complicated. The volume is proportional with the opening angle. So just divide the whole volume by $2\pi$ then multiple the result by $\frac{\pi}6$:

$$\frac{\frac43\pi a^3}{2\pi}\frac{\pi}6=\frac19a^3\pi.$$

Comment: I added in a small explanation. Let me know if you want  more clarification. BTW, I also went through the UMTYMP program - glad to see you on the site!